# Helper method with argument not called from view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, progress-bar

I am implementing a progress bar in Ruby on Rails, and I need to update it when script execution is incremented. I have created a fake increment of progress bar.

**controller/host_controller.rb**

```
require "ruby-progressbar"

module Patchmanagement

  class HostsController < ::HostsController
    helper_method :all
    before_filter :new_action

    def new_action(title, &block)
      import = fork(&block)
      progress = fork do
        #fork Progress bar
        progressbar = ProgressBar.create(title: title, total: nil)
        trap "INT" do
          progressbar.total = 100
          progressbar.finish
          exit
        end
        loop do
          #increment progress bar
          progressbar.increment
          sleep 0.5
        end
      end
      #wait for process to be complete
      Process.wait(import)
      Process.kill(2, progress)
    end
  end
end
```

Calling `new_action` method form view part:

**view/action/new_action.rb**

```
<p>let it be</p>
<% new_action("progress bar") do
  system "/opt/script.sh"
end %>
```

It throws `"wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)"`. When I remove
 `helper_method` symbols it throws `new_action method not found`.

Comment: HTTP and Rails doesn't work like this. You can't update a web page like this. I think the reason it's raising is because you have `before_filter :new_action` -- you don't mean it to be a filter. But it won't work the way you want anyway, things just don't work like that.

Comment: its working fine in separate ruby files. but when i call it from new_action.html.erb file it will following error